# Should I use Spring Data flow server for my new Spring Batch jobs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a requirement to create around 10 Spring Batch jobs, which will consists of a reader and a writer. All readers read data from some different Oracle DB and write into a different Oracle Db(Source and destination servers are different). And the Spring jobs are implemented using Spring Boot. Also all 10+ jobs would be packaged into a single Jar File. So far fine.

Now the client also wants some UI to monitor the job status and act as a job organizer. I gone through the Spring Data flow Server documentation for UI requirement. But I'm not sure whether it'll serve the purpose, or is there any other alternative option available for monitoring the job status, stop and start the jobs whenever required from the UI.

Also how could I separate the the 10+ jobs inside a single Jar in the Spring Data Flow Server if it's the only option for an UI.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observability of spring batch jobs is given by data that are persisted by the framework in a relational database... instances..executions..timestamps...read count..write count....
You have different way to exploit these data. SQL client, JMX, spring batch api (JobExplorer, JobOperator), spring admin (deprecated in favor of cloud data flow server).

Data flow is an orchestrator allowing you to execute data pipelines with streams and tasks(finite and short lived/monitored services). For your jobs we can imagine wrap each jobs in tasks and create a multitask pipeline. Data flow gives you status of each executions.
You can also expose your monitoring data by pushing them as metrics in an influxDb for instance...

Comment: Thanks for the input. Also Wrapping each job (Separate Java class for each job with @EnableBatchJobProcessing) with tasks means, do you want me to add @EnableTask for each batch job class?

Comment: I don't know your jobs definitions but if your jobs are wrapped in tasks you can think about split your monolith batch to a distributed one... So you could take advantage of reusability and  remote processing (chunking/partitionning)... And  yes you need `@EnableTask` with `@EnableBatchProcessing`. Look at this : https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/current/reference/#batch

Answer (score 3):

I don't have reputation to add a comment. So, I am posting answer here. Although I know this is not the way to share reference link as an answer.

This might help you:
[spring-batch-job-monitoring-with-angular-front-end-real-time-progress-bar](https://medium.com/@Ndazi/spring-batch-job-monitoring-with-angular-front-end-real-time-progress-bar-2c843dbce6c4)

Comment: Hi, The application is neat. Thanks for posting that. I'm not sure whether we would be needing a progress bar, but it gives an alternative way.